# Verifying D'Alemberts solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Verify that the D’Alembert solution,

$$u(x, t) = \frac{F(x − at) + F(x + at)}{2}$$

Where $F(x)$ is an odd periodic function of period $2L$ such that $F(x) = f (x)$ on the interval $0 < x < L$, indeed satisfies the initial-boundary value problem by checking that it satisfies the wave equation,

Comment: It looks like this problem is just asking you to differentiate this solution and then plug in.  What do you need help with, exactly?

Comment: We substitute the whole equation into the wave equation?

Comment: You plug in $u_{xx}$ and $u_{tt}$, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with $2 U(x,t) = F(x+at) + F(x-at)$ then it is seen that
\begin{align}
2 \partial_{t} U(x,t) &= a \left( F^{'}(x+at) - F^{'}(x-at) \right) \\
2 \partial_{tt} U(x,t) &= a^{2} \left( F^{''}(x+at) + F^{''}(x-at) \right) \\
2 \partial_{x} U(x,t) &= F^{'}(x+at) + F^{'}(x-at) \\
2 \partial_{xx} U(x,t) &= F^{''}(x+at) + F^{''}(x-at).
\end{align}
This leads to
\begin{align}
2 \left( \partial_{xx} - \frac{1}{a^{2}} \, \partial_{tt} \right) U(x,t) = 0 
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\left( \partial_{xx} - \frac{1}{a^{2}} \, \partial_{tt} \right) U(x,t) = 0 
\end{align}
as desired.